# 2011 ford escape

Tags: ford, power-steering, escape

I lost power steering while driving this morning.  It has an electronic power steering system and there is a sensor recall for some vehicles, but not my vin.
There is no dash warning light on at all and I checked the fuses.  I assume it is a power related issue, but not sure where to check next.
Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you done a visual inspection of the power steering components or checked fluid levels? It could be a dramatic leak or something that is causing it. Also, if it's driven by an electric motor, then that motor could have burned out. A simple way to check would be if there seems to be any burnt smell on the motor or if there are any bubbling labels on its housing.